# Parametrized SOAP request from Tableau Server

Tags: soap, tableau-api

Hello I am working on replacing OBIEE with TS for self service analytics. I am stuck with triggering what is called an ODI action in  OBIEE through TS. Basically I need to pass parameters from my Tableau dash to create a soap request to a third party web service. Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't put many details into your question, but the Tableau features that may prove useful are web data connectors, URL actions, the Tableau JavaScript API and the Tableau Dashboard Extensions API. There is another API, the Analytic Extensions API (aka Tableau Python or TabPy - but can work with other languages) that might be useful as well. The right API depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve. Start at https://www.tableau.com/support/help and look under developer resources

Comment: Through a button on a dash I need to pass an xml with multiple parameters (constant, such as credentials, and variable ones based on selected elements on the dash) to trigger a SOAP request to a third party web service. I do not need to parse the response, only to launch the parametrized request. I was told that a simple URL action from Tableau Server won't work because it is not a REST request, but SOAP.
It is basically aimed at replacing a ODI Invoke action in OBIEE.

Comment: I think the restriction on a URL action is that it uses the HTML GET command. So if your SOAP endpoint accepts GET request, it may work. If your SOAP endpoint requires a POST or other HTML keyword, then you'll need another solution. If so, I'd look first at the Tableau JavaScript API mentioned above. Using a small bit of HTML/CSS and JavaScript with your Tableau viz.